# How to list all files that occur SOMEWHERE in one folder but not another?

Tags: linux, diff

I have a folder with a lot of subfolders and files (let's call it 'orig'), and another folder where a lot of the same files were placed as backups in a different folder structure (let's call it 'backup'). I would like to list all of the files in 'backup' that do not yet exist in 'orig', so that I can put them in the correct subvolder in 'orig' and delete 'backup'. A comparison by file name and size would be sufficient.

Similar questions have been asked before, and the recommended solution is `diff -qr orig/ backup/`. However, when I tried this, I found that the recursion did not work, as the command listed folders that occured in one but not the other, but not the files.
Here is an example. First I create two folders, each with one sub-folder and one file, where each sub-folder and file has a different content:

```
$ mkdir orig
$ mkdir backup
$ mkdir orig/1
$ mkdir backup/2
$ echo 'blah' > orig/1/test.txt
$ ls orig/1
test.txt
$ echo 'blah1' > backup/2/test1.txt
```

Now I compare them using the '-qr' option:

```
$ diff -qr orig/ backup/
Only in orig/: 1
Only in backup/: 2
```

If I descend into the subfolder in one of them, the file in that folder is found:

```
$ diff -r orig/1 backup/
Only in backup/: 2
Only in orig/1: test.txt
```

I actually get the same behaviour with or without '-qr'. Is this a bug or am I misunderstanding diff? I am using diff (GNU diffutils) 3.7.

Any other suggestions for how to solve my problem would be appreciated (e.g. a simple python script).

Comment: Use `hardlink` (Read `man hardlink`) to link identical files in the two directory trees. `find -links 1 old_dir` will find unique files. Check the `hardlinks -n` log for identical files within old_dir. Hint: `grep "old_dir.*old_dir"` the log.

Comment: Thanks for the idea about hardlink! This is amazing. I guess that for the above problem, this would be `hardlink orig backup`, followed by `find backup -links 1`, where the latter would return a list of files that have only one hardlink, i.e. only exist in `backup`. Except that any files that are repeated inside `backup` would also have more than one hardlink, even if they do not exist in `original`, right?

Comment: "Files repeated inside `backup`" are problematic, which is why I suggested `hardlink --verbose --dry-run orig backup |& grep -B3 -A3.  'backup .* -> .*backup'`, to show files in `backup` that will be linked to files in `backup`. Check the surrounding lines for links to `orig`, but I guess I wasn't clear, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way how to solve my problem using python:

```py
import filecmp
import os.path

def find_unique_files(path_orig, path_duplicates, ommit_in_orig=[]):
    """
    Crawls all subfolders of path_duplicates and
    returns list of files (incl. paths) that occur
    in path_duplicates but no-where in path_orig,
    except for folders listed in ommit_in_orig. 
    Do not forget to add trailing '/' at the end of paths.
    
    Arguments:
    path_orig -- string
    path_duplicates -- string
    ommit_in_orig -- list of strings
    
    Returns:
    list of strings indicating paths to files.
    
    Example:
        find_unique_files('/home/user/project/', 
                          '/home/user/project/backups/',
                          ommit_in_orig=['/home/user/project/backups/',
                                         '/home/user/project/temp/'])
    """
    unique_files = []
    for folder, subfolders, files in os.walk(path_duplicates):
        print(folder, end='\r')

        for file in files:
            unique = 1
            filepath = os.path.join(folder,file)
            for folder1, subFolders1, files1 in os.walk(path_orig):
                # Check if folder1 is a subfolder of ommit_in_orig
                ommit = [s for s in ommit_in_orig if s.lower() in folder.lower()]
                if len(ommit) == 0:
                    if file in files1:
                        filepath1 = os.path.join(folder1, file)
                        if filecmp.cmp(filepath,filepath1):
                            # File is identical
                            unique = 0
            if unique == 1:
                unique_files.append(filepath)
    return unique_files
path_orig = 'orig/'
path_duplicates = 'backup/'
find_unique_files(path_orig, path_duplicates)
```